# ubermusic pivot control on android?

Tags: android, windows-phone-7, controls, pivot

I was wondering if anyone is able to tell me how they were able to make the windows UI in the apps UberMusic? I know it's exactly like the windows phone 7 interface and I was wanted to implement that .. anyone know where i could get a tutorial or some source code to look at?

Answer (score 0):

Their re-creating the controls that Silverlight has accessible to the android phone, or using a web based HTML 5.0.

I'm going to go with web based HTML 5.0 as it would be easiest and also cross platformed at a time.

Hope that helps! :)